# What is the correct way to use NSURLConnection return data?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata

What is the difference between the following two code snippets? When I use the first snippet, the requests goes through but data holds 0 bytes, where as in the second case I do get the data. I know the second snippet works but why? I am using synchronous call here.

This one returns 0 bytes of data...

```
NSData *data  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

This one returns correct data...

```
NSData *data ;
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between these two statements. Are you absolutely sure that there's no other modification?

Comment: no other modifications, just change the first to second my app works.